# how to make text centered near images in itemization

Tags: graphics

I need to write few attention signs with explanations, like:

```
|-----|
| pic |- this is text about picture.
|_____|

|-----|
| pic |- this is text about picture.
|_____|

|-----|
| pic |- this is text about picture.
|_____|
```

Maybe any suggestions? Because what I am trying isn't centering my text right. I am trying to do this, like:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item[]\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm]{pic1} -- this is text about picture
\item[]\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm]{pic4} -- this is text about picture
\item[]\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm]{pic3} -- this is text about picture
\end{itemize}
```

And I am getting like this:

```
|-----|
| pic |
|_____|- this is text about picture.

|-----|
| pic |
|_____|- this is text about picture.

|-----|
| pic |
|_____|- this is text about picture.
```

Thanks for help in advance.

```
|-----|
| pic |-blaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaablaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaablaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
|_____|(huge space here)
```

blaaaablabala....................

Comment: @egreg thanks for you answer, but it isn't what I am looking for. It's placing my text wrong. OR I am using this commands incorrect :) Maybe you can show me how to use it with my example?

Comment: @egreg Wow, it's working :) I will try with more text than one line. But I think you save my day, Thank you.

Comment: @egreg One last question :) If my text is more than one line. New line is getting so many space, like this.                                                          `|-----|
| pic |- this is text about picture.
|_____|                                                                                                     text going on and one`   I will add this at my question...

Comment: It's no more a duplicate. I retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `adjustbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\newcommand{\figureitem}[3][]{%
  \item[]%
  \sbox0{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}\ --\ }%
  \makebox[\wd0][l]{\includegraphics[#1,valign=m]{#2}}%
  \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-\wd0}{%
    \makebox[0pt][r]{\ --\ }\ignorespaces#3%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\figureitem[width=2cm,height=2cm]{donald-duck}{
  this is text about picture
}

\figureitem[width=2cm,height=2cm]{donald-duck}{
  this is text about picture which is quite long and wraps across
  lines; let's see what happens
}

\figureitem[width=2cm,height=2cm]{donald-duck}{
  this is text about picture
}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!! It is very smart command, I was trying to do it by myself, but yours is very nice and good example for mine future ones. Thank you again :)